# react-native link and installing native dependencies

Tags: react-native, dependencies

I'm building a React Native module which itself has *native* iOS dependencies, that I don't own.

It's unclear to me how I can refer to and get installed these third-party deps though without making the user just go through Cocoapods directly instead.

i.e. With them having to create a Podfile then add the dependencies to the Podfile and doing `pod install`

**In which case, why use `react-native link` at all?**

So an example project is structured like this:

```
SomeApp
   /iOS
       SomeApp.xcodeproj
       Podfile
   /node_modules
       /my_module
          /ios
              my_module.xcodeproj
              my_module.podspec
              my_module.h
```

`my_module.h` then has specified in it:

```
#import <SomeFramework/SomeFramework.h>
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

and `my_module.podspec` has

```rb
s.dependency 'SomeFramework', '~> 3.0'
```

`react-native link` will link my library but doesn't trigger the install of any dependencies, nor does it add any of those dependencies to the app Podfile.

According to [what information](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cli/tree/3aac9df01ccdbbde157e722ece09527668af32f8/packages/cli/src/link/pods) I can find, `react-native link` *does* look for `podspec` files so it seems like it's only doing half the job?

Is there something I need to add to `my_module/package.json` to make `react-native link` add the dependencies to the main Podfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that your podspec **has** to be in the top level of your node module folder.

If you nest your podspec within an iOS folder, `react-native link` will not find it and will not add it the app's Podfile automatically.